# <input type="file"> how to pass an image in a http-address

Tags: html, input

In the `<input type="file">` I would like to pass a http-address pointing to an image rather than an image in my computer.

does anybody knows how to do that?

Comment: So...basically you want access to the hard drive that tried to upload a picture?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't do that. If you want the user to be able to specify a file either by uploading or by URL, you'll have to provide the alternative in your form (an `<input type="text">` field).

It may appear as if some web browsers on Windows let you type a URL into the file chooser that appears for uploading a local file. This is a built-in feature of the Windows file chooser, and it works by downloading the file onto the user's machine and then uploading it to your web server. It doesn't result in sending of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: It's not possible. Use a `type="text"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution =)

You just have to write in the popup the full html address and vouila =)

Thanks anyway for your comments!

Comment: That is what @Alexey said in his answer. Please click the checkmark by his answer if this is indeed what you were looking for.